# I need a cheap solution for wireless connection in a parking

Tags: wireless, rfid, nfc, system

I want to build a parking system "besides some busy streets" that when a car parks in the specified locations, the system charges something like a card that it's exist on the car or something like an sticker on the body of the car.

I thought about something like NFC but I read it works at the distance under 4cm! and also don't know about it's cost.

Briefly, I like to build a system that, when a car parks in specified location(beside the streets), the system charges the owner of the car for some money related to the parking time automatically!

What's the best idea and way to do it?

Comment: Forget wireless just for now. How about this? A camera at the entrance of the parking garage can read car's licence plate from front face. The time starts just after reading. The same camera can read the licence plate from back face while the car is leaving the parking garage. You have licence plate number and time difference. That's it. Although this needs a detailed image processing but shouldn't be hard on a PC.

Comment: Forget technology - hire a huge parking warden at minimum wage who'll joyfully charge for the parking time or slap a punitive fine on the car owner - a self contained, target oriented mobile recording and action unit or SCTOMRAU for short.

Comment: @Rohat: I did edit the question. the park locations are beside the some streets in the city.

Comment: @Jim: now there is that system you said and we want to change it cause of people complaints. Most of them catch more money from people!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RFID tags can give a substantially longer range than NFC.  Perhaps a few metres for passive tags, or tens of metres for active ones (that contain a bettery).  See [Atlas RFID](http://www.atlasrfid.com/jovix-education/auto-id-basics/active-rfid-vs-passive-rfid/).

Passive tags are pretty cheap.  But you would need one reader for each parking bay.

Comment: Thank you, I will search more about them. but I think they have face to face connection. is there any kind of connection only by distance? something like Bluetooth?

Comment: RFID works by sending radio signals back and forth.  It will work anywhere a radio signal can get through.  I suspect your biggest problem could be that the range is so long that the car triggers not just the parking bay it's in, but all the adjacent ones as well.

Answer (score 0):

The smartphone could be a solution. Driver runs your special application and it's his ticket. Connection to your (=or parking company's) server would be via internet. Car's position would be determined in your application by the coded blinking light that the special lamps emit in the parking site. The application reads that code via smartphone's camera. Also a code display screen could be shooted by the phone's camera, but that's not possible, when driving. GPS is not usable inside and it is often too errorneous.

Simple? Absolutely not, but surely it could be done. Not one man's home project, I think.

The NFC resembling principle should work if you have samelike readers on the gates than the shops and supermarkets have to stop the thieves. Of course the main cost will not be the individual sticker identifying capable readers. The billing system or alternatively the prepaiding system and of course the code sticker logistics will be quite a heavy investment.

Comment: Thanks for nice solution, but park locations are beside the streets and all of the people don't have smartphone or internet access. system should be more common.

Answer (score 0):

Modern Parking Lots use Registration Plate Reading with a camera and OCR software, this doesn't require distributing any cards or dialing with RF data packet collision in a noisy environment with lots of transmitters one in every car.

If you still want to use RF for this purpose, use UHF tags like [this one](http://rfid.atlasrfidstore.com/hs-fs/hub/300870/file-1517968505-pdf/Tech_Spec_Sheets/Misc./ATLAS_Xtreme_Rivet_Jr._Tag.pdf) it works at a distance up to 4.3m, it is waterproof and can be installed in the out side of the vehicle for better reading.

Comment: Thanks for nice solution, but park locations are beside the streets.